# Fail to SSH AWS EC2 even when security group allows all traffic

Tags: amazon-web-services, ssh, amazon-ec2

This is my current security group setting:

[image]

with this setting I could ssh to the server.

However, if I remove the last two entries (with SSH as the Type), I cannot SSH to the server (always timeout).

Why is this? Since I already have the first entry ("all traffic" rule), I thought I don't need the last two SSH rules.

Comment: Your question is confusing. Are you able to SSH when you have the explicit SSH rules? And what is your SG id? Is it sg-93c4aeec?

Comment: if you want to leave open all traffic you need to either: 1. use the 0.0.0.0/0 rule or 2.make sure the Source is correct for the instance.

Comment: @helloV I rephrased my question. Hope this time it is more clear. Yes, sg-93c4aeec is the id of the SG I am using. It shows up under Source by default. Should I always change the `sg-xxxxx` to `0.0.0.0/0` (or some restricted ip range)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/using-network-security.html#security-group-rules

Per AWS, When you specify a security group as the source or destination for a rule, the rule affects all instances associated with the security group. Incoming traffic is allowed based on the private IP addresses of the instances that are associated with the source security group (and not the public IP or Elastic IP addresses).

Comment: Thank you. This solves my confusion. So by default, AWS is being conservative in terms of allowing incoming access.